# eval throws "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'"

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
   Col1    Col2
0  NaN     Type1
1  NaN     Type2
2  NaN     Type1
3  A       Type1
4  NaN     Type1
```

I need to get indices of rows that have `Col1` equal to `NaN` and `Col2` equal to `Type1`. This is what I tried:

```
ix = df.eval("Col1.isna() and Col2== 'Type1'")
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: try `ix = df.eval("Col1.isna() and Col2== 'Type1'", engine='python')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
df.index[df['Col1'].isna() & df['Col2'].eq('Type1')].tolist()
```

This should work, was just able to run it.

Comment: I get the error `KeyError: "Col1.isna() and Col2== 'Type1'"`

Comment: Now it returns an empty list. But if I run each condition separately, I get correct True/False distribution. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: @Fluxy. It should work now. Instead of using `==`, switch to `.eq()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[(df['Col1'].isna())&(df['Col2'].eq('Type1'))]
```

Comment: And I need to get the indices, not the rows of `df`.